# How can I catch moment SKScene became paused or audioEngine became stopped?

Tags: swift, swift2, skscene, avaudioengine

How can I catch moment SKScene became paused or audioEngine became stopped?

I have two SKScenes: GameScene and EndScene, and I play sounds during the game using audioEngine property of GameScene (this property contains AVAudioEngine object). When the game is over, the scene changes from GameScene to EndScene:

```
        self.view?.presentScene(EndScene())
```

After this, when user touches «Restart», the game starts again, scene changes back from EndScene to GameScene:

```
        self.view?.presentScene(GameScene(), transition: SKTransition.crossFadeWithDuration(1.0))
```

When scene changes from EndScene to GameScene, GameScene became paused for one second (because of parameter value SKTransition.crossFadeWithDuration(1.0)). Because of GameScene became paused, audioEngine also became stopped. After this, GameScene automatically starts, but audioEngine don’t starts and stays stopped. Then, the game crashes at the first attempt to play the sound, and it’s clear: because audioEngine is stopped. 
To avoid this I need to start audioEngine after it was stopped, but there is a problem to catch the moment it happens: I’ve tried to catch it in didMoveToView() of GameScene, but there GameScene is not paused, it became paused later, after didMoveToView() was already finished. 
And this is my question:
How can I catch moment SKScene became paused or audioEngine became stopped? Are there some suitable notifications or event handlers for this case, maybe?

Answer (score 1):

Finally, i've dropped attempts to find some suitable notifications or events and decided to check audioEngine status every time before sound playback, in function plays sound. I rate this way as reasonably efficient:

```
func playSound(soundType: Sounds) {

    if !audioEngine.running {
        do {
            try audioEngine.start()
        } catch {
        }
    }

    var soundNode = SKAudioNode()
    var waitingDuration = Double()

    switch soundType {
    case .enemyDestroyed:
        soundNode = SKAudioNode(fileNamed: "Blip001.wav")
        waitingDuration = 3
    case .playerDestroyed:
        soundNode = SKAudioNode(fileNamed: "Noise002.wav")
        waitingDuration = 5
    }

    soundNode.autoplayLooped = false

    self.addChild(soundNode)
    soundNode.runAction(SKAction.changeVolumeTo(0.5, duration: 0))
    soundNode.runAction(SKAction.changeReverbTo(0.5, duration: 0))
    soundNode.runAction(SKAction.sequence([SKAction.play(), SKAction.waitForDuration(waitingDuration), SKAction.removeFromParent()]))

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `update` function to check for this every time a frame is called (60 times per second). Inside it, put a conditional statement (if, while, etc.) that checks for the condition you want. For example, use this to check for if the scene is paused:

```
override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {

if isPaused == true {

// Code to run when scene is paused

       }

}
```

Note that this is in Swift 3 and in lower versions `isPaused` is just `paused`

Another option could be to use loops like `while` and `do-while` to continuously check for the conditions

Comment: Before ask my question i have thought about using update() event for catch this, but it seemed to me it's quite rough way. The way using do-while (at the end of didMoveToView, as i suggest you mean) looks much more efficent, thanks for this advice. But, finally, i've decided to check audioEngine status every time before sound playback, in function plays sound. I rate this way as reasonably efficient. I've posted it as answer to my own question below.